# Maven Plugin/Profile Issue

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testng

I am an automation qa engineer and I've been charged with setting up our Jenkins CI framework. The issue that I am having is that Maven is failing in the build phase. In looking at the log there a few things that are concerning to me but I am not sure if they are related or relevant. See the log below

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\dmohamed>mvn test -PCustomerFSNRegressionSuite
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
Envi_Test:Maven:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.qas.qtest.api:qtest-sdk-a
gent:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}\src\
Libs\qtest-sdk-java-1.1.0.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line
42, column 17
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.qas.qtest.api:qtest-testn
g-agent:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}\s
rc\Libs\qtest-testng-agent-1.0.0.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects
@ line 50, column 17
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten t
he stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support buildin
g such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Maven ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\dmohamed\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Maven ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Ma
ven ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\dmohamed\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Maven -
--
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ Maven ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.190 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-02T08:25:01-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/307M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "CustomerFSNRegressionSuite" could not be activa
ted because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
19.1:test (default-test) on project Maven: Unable to parse configuration of mojo
 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test for parameter proper
ties: Missing name in properties -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginConfigur
ationException

C:\Users\dmohamed>
```

my concerns are specifically these lines

```
INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\dmohamed\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Maven ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Ma
ven ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory 

C:\Users\dmohamed\src\test\resources
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Maven -
    --
    [INFO] No sources to compile

WARNING] The requested profile "CustomerFSNRegressionSuite" could not be activa
ted because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
19.1:test (default-test) on project Maven: Unable to parse configuration of mojo
 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test for parameter proper
ties: Missing name in properties -> [Help 1]
```

It seems as though when I attempt to run the mvn commands it tries to reference srs folders that don't exist (not sure if this does any harm) it doesn't recognize my TestnNG profile specified in my POM file (I am assuming this will impact Jenkins) and there is some property/configuration error in my pom file (Per the ERROR message in my log) that I cannot resolve.  See my POM file below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Envi_Test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Maven</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    </properties>
        <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>CustomerFSNRegressionSuite</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>


    </profiles>

    <dependencies>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>2.53.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
                <version>2.53.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.5</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am sorry if this is a repost, I looked but I did not see a question regarding a circumstance like this.

Comment: What do you mean, *it tries to reference srs folders that don't exist*? Where are your source folders?

Comment: The filepath that the mvn commands attempt to use to locate the srs folders is incorrect, I do not know how to point the commands elsewhere  either.

Comment: Ok but what would be the correct path?

Comment: C:\Users\dmohamed\Documents\Testing Environment\Maven\FCS_Regression_Suite\trunk\src

Comment: I figured as much. Don't do that. Respect the [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and put your sources under `src/main/java`, and test sources under `src/test/java`.